# Display Empty String If Date Is NULL

Tags: datatables

I'm using JQuery Datatables and within one of the columns in my table I'm displaying dates. The problem is, some of the date data I'm passing to the column will be NULL and therefore displayed to the user within the table as 01/01/0001.

```
$('#dataTables-example').dataTable({

            "bServerSide": true,
            "sAjaxSource": "/Survey/GetAjaxData",
            "fnServerParams": function ( aoData ) {
                aoData.push( { "name": "id", "value": "40" }, 
                    { "name": "typeID", "value": "38" }
                    );
            },
            "bProcessing": true,
            "bJQueryUI": true,
            "aoColumns": [
                      null,
                      null, //Display Date Column
                      null,
            ]

        });
```

Is there any function/ code that can be added to my dataTable declaration above that will allow me to check if the data column contains value 01/01/0001 then instead display 'No Date' to the user?

Any help would be greatly appreciated with this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is a bit late, but I've just done this like so:

```
"aoColumns": [
                null,
                {
                  'mRender': function (data, type, full) {
                       if(full[1] != null){
                            // display date
                            return full[1];
                       }else{
                            return "No Date";
                      }
                   }
                }
```